# Prevent an HTML5 video from playing when the play button is paused

Tags: javascript, html, video, preventdefault

I have a video embedded in a site, and when a user plays the video I have JS to expand the video to the width of the site (and then shrink it on pause).

The video is being played/paused using the built-in controls, but when the video plays while expanding, it just looks weird, hence my desire to prevent playing until after the expansion.

However, `preventDefault();` doesn't seem to be working in this instance. Does anyone know a way of achieving this? Thanks.

Here is my JS -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var video = $('#intro-video');

    video.on('play', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        video.animate({
            height:     '506',
            width:      '900'
        }, 500);

    });

    video.on('pause', function(e){

        video.animate({
            height:     '200',
            width:      '356'
        }, 500);

    });

});
```

And here is the HTML source -

```
<video id="intro-video" controls="">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.somesite.com/video.mp4"></source>
    Sorry, your browser is old and doesn't support the HTML5 'video' tag. Sucks to be you...
</video>
```

Comment: Is there a play button that's calling video.play() somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the controls are shown and this is how the video is being played. But I need to essentially prevent the play action until the video is full size, and then play. I'll update the question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Post up some HTML too, please.

Comment: Already done in my last edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the inbuilt player controls, the video will start when you press play, and I don't believe you can prevent the event at this point in javascript.

I would recommend looking into creating your own controls for the player. That way, you can listen for the click event on the play button, and control the playback for the video directly.

Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is what I've done here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6gXL/2/)

Basically, when the video starts to play, pause it. Do the animation, then play it once the animation's finished. I've created a variable so the pause animation doesn't get triggered when we manually pause it:

```
var video = $('#intro-video');
var enlarged = false;

video.on('play', function(e){
    if (!enlarged){
        video[0].pause();
        video.animate({
            height:     '506',
            width:      '900'
        }, 500, function() {
            enlarged = true;
            video[0].play();
        });
    }
});

video.on('pause', function(e){
    if (enlarged) {
        enlarged = false;
        video.animate({
            height:     '200',
            width:      '356'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a good logical way of approaching the issue, and it appears to work perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it works. I've noticed there can be a split-second of audio/video that plays just as you click it - so it's not ideal. I'd like to know if it definitely isn't possible for the event listener to stop the playing of the video, but in chrome at least, it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I've found a few references also suggesting it's not, which is a shame; it seems a bit daft to be honest, but maybe there is a good reason. However, I really don't want to have to code a complete custom control bar, so I'll take the split second of play that occurs in Chrome! Firefox and IE both seem absolutely fine though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's very simple:

```
let videoShouldNotPlay = true
video.onplay = function () {
    if (videoShouldNotPlay) {
      video.pause()
      video.currentTime = 0 // set to the current time needed
      alert("You can't play the video right now")
      return
    }
}
```